# facebook getuser. It always returns zero

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Kindly have a glance at my code..

```
 <?php
 require_once 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'apppID',
  'secret' => 'sercretCode',
  'cookie' =>'true'
));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Facebook PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php
    //get user from facebook object
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user): //check for existing user id
        echo '<p>User ID: ', $user, '</p>';
    else: //user doesn't exist
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'diplay'=>'popup',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/returnpath/'
        ));
        echo '<p><a href="', $loginUrl, '" target="_top">login</a></p>';
    endif; //check for user id
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, getUser() method always returns 0 and goes into else. I always get "Login" like, its the same even if I log in. Kindly let me know if any issues. I've already seen many questions of this way but none solved the problem exactly.. My appid and secret key are correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SDK docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) you will get a value of zero on `$facebook->getUser()` if the user has not been logged in.

- Try logging in as that user in facebook and then call the getUser() method.
- is 'cookie' => 'true' optional? if so, try removing that config parameter.  Make sure your facebook object is being created.
- Check your logs to see if the code is not generating any errors.

Comment: I've tried to login. But even after login the return is Zero. Cookie is optional. But, even if I remove that doesn't solve, Let me know if you have any other procedure... This is the very first step which I'm not able to get with.

Answer (score 0):

Well!! Most of the people, including me, are curious to make their app just in no time after they register the app. I made no changes to the above code.

**By default, to grand access to the app FB takes 24 hours**. So, you won't be able to get userid or any details regarding user. Kindly wait for 24hours.

Comment: You didn't change any code, you waited 24 hours, and now it works? This might be useful for other people to know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am stuck with the same ----, totally desesperated, how about this solution?